# does MongoDB shell executes javascript methods?

Tags: mongodb

I was executing db.myCollectionname.remove({}) in the MongoDB Shell, but by mistake I ran a command db.myCollectionname.remove, and mongoDB had shown me the following method in the console.

```
function (t, justOne) {
    var parsed = this._parseRemove(t, justOne);
    var query = parsed.query;
    var justOne = parsed.justOne;
    var wc = parsed.wc;
    var collation = parsed.collation;

    var result = undefined;
    var startTime =
        (typeof(_verboseShell) === 'undefined' || !_verboseShell) ? 0 : new Date().getTime();

    if (this.getMongo().writeMode() != "legacy") {
        var bulk = this.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
        var removeOp = bulk.find(query);

        if (collation) {
            removeOp.collation(collation);
        }

        if (justOne) {
            removeOp.removeOne();
        } else {
            removeOp.remove();
        }

        try {
            result = bulk.execute(wc).toSingleResult();
        } catch (ex) {
            if (ex instanceof BulkWriteError || ex instanceof WriteCommandError) {
                result = ex.toSingleResult();
            } else {
                // Other exceptions thrown
                throw Error(ex);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (collation) {
            throw new Error("collation requires use of write commands");
        }

        this._validateRemoveDoc(t);
        this.getMongo().remove(this._fullName, query, justOne);

        // enforce write concern, if required
        if (wc)
            result = this.runCommand("getLastError", wc instanceof WriteConcern ? wc.toJSON() : wc);
    }

    this._printExtraInfo("Removed", startTime);
    return result;
}
```

It seems like a java script method? is it a Node.js method? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do check out this link [MongoDB API](https://api.mongodb.com/) as we can see MongoDB uses the JavaScript API in its **MongoDB mongo Shell**

Comment: yes I found it, https://api.mongodb.com/js/3.3.4/symbols/src/src_mongo_shell_collection.js.html thanks